# json形式のデータにおいて特定の値の取り出し方について

Tags: javascript, json

総務省統計局のe-statのAPIを利用して日本の総人口のデータをjsonで取得しました。

そのjsonデータの中で自分の目当ての値のみ変数に格納したいのですが、いくら調べてもやり方がわからないでいます。

そもそもそのようなことができるのかわかりませんが、なにか助言を頂けるとありがたいです。

使用言語はjavascriptです。

Comment: 取得したJSONデータと目当ての値を提示できますか？

Answer (score 1):

> jsonで取得しました。

jsonとはjson文字列のことですか？
パースしてObjectから取得してはどうでしょう？
パースした結果、多次元配列なのかどうか構造が分かりませんが……

```
//json文字列
var json_data = '{"suffix1":"value1","suffix2":"value2","suffix3":"value3"}';
//JSONをパース
var data = JSON.parse(json_data);
alert(data["suffix1"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

こんにちは

JSONデータを表示する感じでしょうか？
昔、QiitaでjQueryを使用して取得するサンプル記事を書いたことがあったのでリンク貼っておきます。ご参考までに。

http://qiita.com/miiitaka/items/f77cb83b9dfcd05aea82