# Jsonの中にある情報の取り出し方を知りたい

Tags: jquery, json

productsの中にあるproduct_idの番号を取得してnameやmain_imageを取得してJqueryで表示させたい場合、どのような記述が必要なんでしょうか。おしえてください。

```
{
    "products": [
        {
            "product_id": "11",
            "product_code_min": "inf02",
            "product_code_max": "inf02",
            "name": "インフルブロックのどあめ ブルーベリー味",
            "comment1": null,
            "comment2": null,
            "comment3": null,
            "main_list_comment": "<燕の巣を使った奇跡のキャンディ>",
            "main_image": "11020721_56369067217cb.jpg",
            "main_list_image": "11020721_563690672a095.jpg",
            "main_large_image": "11020721_56369067196de.jpg",
            "price01_min": null,
            "price01_max": null,
            "price02_min": "2500",
            "price02_max": "2500",
            "stock_min": null,
            "stock_max": null,
            "stock_unlimited_min": "1",
            "stock_unlimited_max": "1",
            "deliv_date_id": "2",
            "status": "1",
            "del_flg": "0",
            "update_date": "2017-08-24 10:14:46",
            "price01_min_inctax": null,
            "price01_max_inctax": null,
            "price02_min_inctax": 2700,
            "price02_max_inctax": 2700,
            "price01_min_format": "0",
            "price01_max_format": "0",
            "price02_min_format": "2,500",
            "price02_max_format": "2,500",
            "price01_min_inctax_format": "0",
            "price01_max_inctax_format": "0",
            "price02_min_inctax_format": "2,700",
            "price02_max_inctax_format": "2,700",
            "price01_min_tax_format": "0",
            "price01_max_tax_format": "0",
            "price02_min_tax_format": "2,700",
            "price02_max_tax_format": "2,700",
            "papc2": {
                "value_id": "103",
                "product_id": "11",
                "column_id": "2",
                "value": "11181905_564c4d7b4000e.jpg",
                "name": "サムネイル画像01",
                "type": "image",
                "required": "0",
                "max_length": null
            },
            "papc3": {
                "value_id": "104",
                "product_id": "11",
                "column_id": "3",
                "value": "01271507_588ae396af94a.jpg",
                "name": "サムネイル画像02",
                "type": "image",
                "required": "0",
                "max_length": null
            },
            "papc4": {
                "value_id": "101",
                "product_id": "11",
                "column_id": "4",
                "value": "東京都",
                "name": "原産地",
                "type": "text",
                "required": "0",
                "max_length": "50"
            },
            "papc5": {
                "value_id": "102",
                "product_id": "11",
                "column_id": "5",
                "value": "常温",
                "name": "常温・冷蔵・冷凍",
                "type": "text",
                "required": "0",
                "max_length": "50"
            }
        }
```

Comment: とりあえず、[こちらのスレッド](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/20940/13972)をよく読んでみてください。質問内容が不明確な上、回答にある例もあなたの挙げられた例より簡単なものですが、何がしかの役には立つかと思います。うまくいかない部分があるときは、完全に動かなくても良いので、ご自身のコードを質問に追記されると、回答がつきやすいと思います。(ご自身の質問は「編集」できるはずです。)

Comment: (先のコメントでリンク先を間違えていました。もしリンクを辿ろうとして、「なんじゃこりゃ?」と思われたら、修正しましたのでもう一度試してみてください。)

Comment: [マルチポスト先](https://teratail.com/questions/147405)ではmapを使ってJSONを連想配列化する回答例が寄せられていますね。どちらの回答もJSONの取得にJQueryを使っていませんが、お好みの方法でよろしいかと存じます。

Answer (score 2):

productsの内容をリスト表示するサンプルコードを知りたいという質問でしたら、下記のサンプルコードが参考になるでしょうか。

```
<html>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    function showProducts() {
        var data = {
        "products": [
            {
                "product_id": "11",
                "name": "インフルブロックのどあめ ブルーベリー味",
                "main_image": "11020721_56369067217cb.jpg",
                "papc2": {
                    "value_id": "103",
                    "product_id": "11" 
                }
            },
            {
               "product_id": "12",
               "name": "タミフルブロックのどあめ ブラックベリー入り",
               "main_image": "11020721_56369067217cb.jpg",
               "papc2": {
                   "value_id": "104",
                   "product_id": "12" 
               }
            }
        ]}
        var products = data.products;
        for(var i in products){
            $("#output").append("<li>" + products[i].product_id + " : " + products[i].name + "<img src=\"" + products[i].main_image + "\"/></li>");
        }
    }
    </script>
<body onload="showProducts()">
    <ul id="output"></ul>
</body>
</html>
```

もし「質問文のJSONが不正なのでエラーが発生する」「外部のURLからJSONが取得できない」「自作のスクリプトで期待通りの表示ができない」など、別の内容で困っているならば @OOPer さんの指摘通り、作成中のコードや要件を明示するとより適切な回答が得やすいと思います。